# Communication via Signals between two seperate classes

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-signals

I am currently working on a Project in which I have to process data from measurements.
This data will be stored in a list, that I `emit` as a Signal using `pyqtSignal`. This List is emited constantly in a Worker-class which is gathering the values within a Loop. This is currently working. Now i want to implement a new Worker-class, which also needs this emited list to process it in a funktion.
My problem is, that the second Worker does not invoke the function within the `.connect` function.
I am a beginner, so please excuse any mistakes I made.

I want to seperate the Workers because, the First is just for the meaasurement and the second has to process the data, so I can run them seperately when I need it. Furthermore I want that the MainApp(the Gui), always is working fluently, because worker1 will operate a long time.
The following code does not work:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, uic
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject
from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread, pyqtSignal

import time

"""MainApplication"""

class MainApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        guiPath = "/home/pi/main.ui"
        self.ui = uic.loadUi(guiPath,self)
       
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.startWorker1)
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.stopWorker1)
        self.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(self.changeTestStat)
        self.pushButton_4.clicked.connect(self.changeTestStat)

        self.threadPool  = {}
       
        self.pushButton_2.setEnabled(False)
        self.pushButton_3.setEnabled(False)
        self.pushButton_4.setEnabled(False)
        
        self.toExcel = False
        self.testStat = False

    def startWorker1(self):
        self.threadPool[1] = Worker1()       
        self.worker1 = self.threadPool[1]
        print("starting Worker")
        self.worker1.start()

        #this function updates the shown values:
        self.worker1.signalDF.connect(self.showCurrMeasVals)

        self.pushButton.setEnabled(False)
        self.pushButton_2.setEnabled(True)
        self.pushButton_3.setEnabled(True)
    
    def startWorker2(self):
        self.threadPool[2] = Worker2()
        self.worker2 = self.threadPool[2]
        self.worker2.start()

    
    def changeTestStat(self):
        if self.testStat:
            self.testStat = False
            self.pushButton_3.setEnabled(True)
            self.pushButton_4.setEnabled(False)
            self.worker2.stop()
        else:
            self.testStat = True
            self.pushButton_3.setEnabled(False)
            self.pushButton_4.setEnabled(True)
            self.startWorker2()

    def stopWorker1(self):
        print("stopping Worker")
        self.worker1.stop()
        self.pushButton.setEnabled(True)
        self.pushButton_2.setEnabled(False)
        self.pushButton_3.setEnabled(False)
        self.pushButton_4.setEnabled(False)

    def showCurrMeasVals(self,data:list):
        self.lineEdit.setText(str(data[5]))
        self.lineEdit_2.setText(str(data[9]))
        self.lineEdit_3.setText(str(data[1])
        self.lineEdit_4.setText(str(data[2]))
        self.lineEdit_5.setText(str(data[3]))
        self.lineEdit_6.setText(str(data[7]))
        self.lineEdit_7.setText(str(data[6]))

"""Signal-class"""
class Sig(QObject):
    signal = pyqtSignal(list)
    
"""Worker1-class for measurement"""    
class Worker1(QThread):
    signal = Sig.signal

    def run(self):
        self.Loop = True
        while self.Loop:
            try:
                #Here is the function for the measurement located. it returns the data as a list
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
                break
            self.signal.emit(data)  # here will the list be emited
            time.sleep(0.2)
    
    def stop(self):
        self.Loop = False
        self.exit()

"""second worker-class to use the data in a Function seperated from the first Worker"""
class Worker2(QThread):
    signal = SigDF.signal
    def run(self):
        self.signal.connect(self.procData) # here, do i want do invoke the funktion to process the              
                                           # data every time the list is emited in Worker-class 1.
    def procData(self,data:list):
        data1 = data[0] #those are the needed elements of the list
        data2 = data[2]
        self.procData1(data1)
        self.procData2(data2)
  
    def stop(self):
        self.exit()
    
    def procData1(self,data1):
        #Here the data1 will be processed

    def procData2(self,data2):
        #Here the data2 will be processed

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication.instance()
    mainWindow = MainApp()
    mainWindow.show()
```

I shortened the Code a bit, but only things that are not necessary.

It worked, when I added this line to the `startWorker2` function in the MainApp-class:

```
self.worker1.signal.connect(self.worker2.procdata)
```

but in this Case, the MainApp has to invoke the Funktion every time it emits the signal.
However I want it to be in a seperate Worker, so the MainApp/Gui can operate fluently.
I am thankful for every suggestion.

Comment: Can you fix the syntax errors on your code so we have a minimum reproducible example? It would make it easier to help you. Apart from that, correct me if I didn't understand correctly the issue, but I believe that connecting the signal to both slots would give you what you want (by both slots I mean worker2 and the showCurrMeasVals on the MainApp)

Comment: @FredericNoß What is `SigDF`? And why are you creating a further class just for the signal? All QObject descendants can have signals on their own, creating a separate class for that is just pointless, especially since you're not actually using it and you're fundamentally creating a new signal for the other QThread subclass anyway. Your usage of those signals makes little sense, as it is overriding `run()` just to create a connection. It's actually unclear why you need a further QThread: if you believe that using two threads would optimize computation, sorry but you're wrong. ->

Comment: @FredericNoß Python does not allow real thread concurrency, so you will probably have no benefit at all in having a thread for data gathering and another for their processing: they will **never** be accessed at the same time, but **always** alternately when the GIL allows it. In fact, it's even possible that using two threads for that will actually worsen performance. Please [edit] your question and improve its explanation (how is `data` retrieved? when?), but be aware that your usage of signals is quite nonsensical (signals are bound to instances, you cannot use their classes as reference).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, I wanted to create a Thread for each Task the Project has to do. Measuring a signal of a Temp-sensor in a Loop, and processing those values within an other Loop  (Thread) for a regulation of a temperature for example. I will use just one worker-class now and see if I can fix the issue. Thank you very much for your support! I will get back to you if I don't make any process